# Python-How to resolve TypeError

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

```
 import urllib, urllib2
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
 url='http://www.amazon.in/product-reviews/B00EJBA7HC/ref=cm_cr_pr_top_link_1?ie=UTF8&pageNumber=1&showViewpoints=0&sortBy=bySubmissionDateDescending'
 content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
 soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
 fooId = soup.find('input',name='ASIN',type='hidden') #Find the proper tag
 value = fooId['value']
 print value
```

I need this code to print the ASIN ID for the product from the URL given.

Instead, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: find() got multiple values for keyword argument 'name'
```

Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why this is breaking is because you have the soup.find function signature wrong. There is no first positional argument. The function signature looks like this:

```
def find(self, name=None, attrs={}, recursive=True, text=None, **kwargs)
```

So 'input' is assigned to the first keyword argument(in this case, name). So now you have 2 values assigned to keyword argument 'name'.

The correct syntax for what you are trying to do is likely this:

```
fooId = soup.find(name='input', attrs={'name': 'ASIN', 'type': 'hidden'})
```

This says, find all `<input>`'s in the HTML you are parsing with the attributes listed described in attrs.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got the required output!